# Using `waitress` to serve a Django app on multiple ports

Tags: python, wsgi, waitress

I'm using `waitress` to serve my Django app. I need it to serve the app on two ports simultaneously, in the same thread. (Can't be on a separate process because I need to be able to run it in my debugger in development.)

How can I do that?

Comment: Let your reverse proxy serve the content from a different port.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of waitress is now able to listen on multiple sockets, including IPv4 and IPv6.

Instead of passing in a host/port combination you now provide `waitress` with a space delineated list, and it will create as many sockets as required.

```
from waitress import serve
serve(wsgiapp, listen='0.0.0.0:8080 [::]:9090 *:6543')
```

Comment: If you use a configuration file, replace the "host" and "port" entries in [server:main] with "listen".

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `waitress`, but [the latest documentation](http://waitress.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) doesn't seem to mention using multiple ports. A quick clone and ack for 'port' and 'socket' through [the code](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/) helped me find `runner.py` with documented command-line options, and the option `--port=PORT` doesn't seem to support multiple ports. That's not proof, but a good indication without digging too deep.

If I were to take a stab at adding this feature to `waitress`, then it sounds like `select` is what's needed.

Here's a [StackOverflow example that uses `select` to bind a basic `server` to multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232387/2125392).